# how can I run a java program automaticlly

Tags: job-scheduling

I have a java package,
I want to my program be runned every night at 0 o'clock automaticlly,
how can I do this work?

Comment: In a way that nothing to do with the fact that it is a Java program. This is probably for serverfault or superuser.

Comment: Exactly as any other program, with `Programmed Tasks` in Windows and `cron` in Linux/Unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you have 2 solutions:

1. Create application that runs your code every night, i.e. implement scheduling yourself. Obviously you can (and should) use tools that help you to do scheduling.
2. Use OS-specific tools. For example cron for unix and windows task scheduler for windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can either schedule in your own OS. On *nix, there is [cron](http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html). I'm not sure what is used in windows.

Or you can make your own java program schedule: on running it, it sets a times to execute your task in a specific time.

You could use a `Thread.sleep()` counting the time from now until midnight, but that's a poor-man's solution. [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is your man, as it works schedulling your tasks.

If you choose the schedulling path, you can't forget to run your application in the OS startup